# Why can't I launch IDLE after installing Anaconda?

Tags: windows, anaconda, python-idle

I recently installed Anaconda. Ever since then, clicking IDLE from the Windows Start selection results in the computer loading for half an second, then absolutely nothing happening. I can still run IDLE from the Anaconda Prompt, but it won't let me run the editor Spyder at the same time (also from the Anaconda Prompt).

Edit: Typing "py -m idlelib" into the Windows Command Prompt works to start IDLE! That's great, and thank you to Terry Jan Reedy for suggesting it in the comments.

I'm still wondering why installing Anaconda caused the IDLE shortcut from Windows Start to stop working?

Comment: What is the difference between 'loading' and 'nothing happening'?  What if you instead enter 'py 3.x -m idlelib', where 'x' is replaced by the appropriate number of 'python3.x' on the start men, into command prompt?

Comment: "nothing happening" means it stops loading and then it's like I never clicked on it.

Comment: And when I enter 'py 3.8 -m idlelib' in the Command Prompt, I get an interesting error: "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\name\3.8': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

Type "py -m idlelib" into Windows Command Prompt.